# Stacked bar chart from chartjs mysql

Tags: php, mysql, charts, chart.js, stacked-bar-chart

i am struggling to make chartjs stacked bar chart from MySQL table. Here is the JSON response and codes and I want to know how to put it into the stacked bar chart.

**Sql query**

```
function getStudentMark()
{
    $query = "SELECT machine_type,line, COUNT(*) as linewise FROM dr_scan  GROUP BY machine_type,line";
    $result = $this->dbConn->select($query);
    return $result;
}
```

**get_chart.php**

```
<?php
use wacoal\Util;
use wacoal\Student;

header('Content-Type: application/json');

require_once __DIR__ . '/../lib/wacoal.php';
$student = new Machine();
$result = $student->getMachine();


$data = array();
$data2 = array();

require_once __DIR__ . '/../lib/Util.php';
$util = new Util();

$type = "bar";
if (! empty($_GET["chart_type"])) {
    $type = $_GET["chart_type"];
}

switch ($type) {
                
    case "vertical-bar":
        foreach ($result as $k => $v) {
            $data[$k] = array(
                "label" => $result[$k]["machine_type"],
                    "labels" => $result[$k]["line"],
                
                "data" => [
                    $result[$k]["linewise"]
                ],
                'backgroundColor' => $util->getRandomColor()
            );
        };
        
            
}
$data = json_encode($data);
echo str_replace("},","},\n",$data);
```

**output json**

```
[{"label":"3 th O\/L","labels":"1","data":[3],"backgroundColor":"#ac9f0d"},
{"label":"Button Attach","labels":"2","data":[1],"backgroundColor":"#74589b"},
{"label":"Button Attach","labels":"5","data":[2],"backgroundColor":"#3abea2"},
{"label":"Double Needle","labels":"1","data":[1],"backgroundColor":"#3aacb0"},
{"label":"Single Needle","labels":"1","data":[3],"backgroundColor":"#df9001"}]
```

**Chart **
Here is the chartjs script.

```
function showStackedVerticalChart() {
    {
        $.post("ajax-endpoint/get-chart-data.php?chart_type=vertical-bar",
            function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                var name = [];
            
                for (var i in data) {
                    name.push(data[i].labels);
                
                }
                
                                
                var chartdata = {
                    labels: name,
                    datasets: data
                };

                var graphTarget = $("#stacked-vertical-chart");

                var graph = new Chart(graphTarget, {
                    type: 'bar',
                    data: chartdata,
                    options: {
                        
                        scales: {
                            xAxes: [{
                                barPercentage: 0.3,
                                stacked: true
                            }],
                            yAxes: [{
                                stacked: true
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
    }
}
```

**This is the final output that I want**
[image]

**This is the output now I am seeing**
[image]

Appreciate your help. I am new to this

Comment: It is not clear what the problem is here but one thing to note - `json_encode` has the `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` option available which would mean you do not need to manually edit the string to get new line characters as above. Please clarify what is not working

Comment: Have you tried using it with static json data first to learn how the chart works and needs? If not, start there. Then you fetch the data from MySQL and restructure it to fit the require format. Right now, I'm not sure if you're asking how to create a stacked bar chart in chart.js in general (which they explain in their documentation), or if it is how to restructure the data from the database, but then you need to give us an example of the structure you're after.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I uploaded the image. can you check it?

Comment: After the edits, this appears to be a very clear question. The structure of the resulting javascript  data (and probably of the options) does not correspond to  the format required by chart.js. The only missing detail is the version of chart.js used.

Comment: Hello @kikon version of chartjs is 2.8.0

Comment: I wasn't expecting that, it seems for the older `2.8.0` version of chart.js, things are pretty good. Now, the data you show is not enough for the kind of result you present in the second image - you have just one data point per dataset. With your data I get [this](https://jsfiddle.net/zp091dn5/). As for labels, they are repeating, so you have to find another way to extract them from data, like generating them with something like `labels = Array.from({length: 5}, (_, i)=>''+(i+1))`